# integrate Firebase storage with Google cloud CDN

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, google-cdn, google-cloud-cdn

i'm making an app using firebase.

photos uploaded by users are saved in firebase storage.

I use firebase cloud functions to make thumbnails to load photo feed faster,

but in one page, I need to load original photos(max 30 pics) at once.

To load original photos faster, I want to use google cloud CDN.

I followed docs here [google cloud cdn docs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/quickstart) , made load balancer and cdn

[image]

I can see Cloud CDN : Enabled (that Backend buckets are my firebase storage), but it seems to be not working.

in my app, I load those pictures with firebase storage urls which look like 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....'.

How can I integrate my firebase storage with google cloud cdn??

Answer (score 5):

Using `firebasestorage.googleapis.com` sounds like the problem here. [When you set up Cloud CDN in your project](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn), you had to create an HTTP(S) Load-Balancer in order to expose a bucket. Cloud CDN will only kick in if you're accessing your data via that Load-Balancer. Try accessing the Load-Balancer's public IP instead of the `firebase` URL. You can find the IP address right there in the same page you've screenshot. Finally, don't forget to make sure the files you want to make available via the CDN [obey these restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching).

Comment: What if the files are not public? How do you integrate the `Firebase Authentication` ?